# Python time.sleep method not working properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, sleep

I have written this small code in Python. It should print every character in a string with a small sleeptime between them...

```
import time, sys

def writeText(string, t):
    i = 0
    while i < len(string):
        sys.stdout.write(string[i])
        time.sleep(float(t))
        i += 1

writeText("Hello World", 0.5)
```

but it only prints the whole string after 0.5 seconds... I often have this issue but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.stdout.flush()` might solve your problem.

```
import time, sys

def writeText(string, t):
    i = 0
    while i < len(string):
        sys.stdout.write(string[i])
        time.sleep(float(t))
        i += 1
        sys.stdout.flush()

writeText("Hello World", 0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you! Code is working fine now..

Answer (score 3):

You should add

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

after writing, to force the output of the text.

Comment: Thank you code is working fine now!